# Interpretation ARIMA dummy variables

Tags: r, arima, interpretation, categorical-encoding

I'm doing an ARIMA analisys with monthly dummy variables and other covariables. I'm wondering how to interpret the coefficients of my month dummy variables, as I don't have 12 months and I haven't an Intercept row.

```
x_reg_dummy <- seasonaldummy(ts(dat[,`Var_tx`],f=12))

ts_cov<- ts(dat[,`Var_tx`],start=c(2010,1),frequency = 12)
model <- auto.arima(ts_cov, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE,
                    xreg = cbind(as.matrix(dat[,.(`V1`,`V2`,
                                              `V3`,`V4`,
                                              `V5`,`V6`,
                                              `V7`)]),x_reg_dummy))
```

The coefficients I get :

```
z test of coefficients:

                    Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
ma1                -0.907781   0.100311 -9.0496 < 2.2e-16 ***
ma2                -0.050682   0.115798 -0.4377 0.6616225    
ma3                 0.226099   0.091052  2.4832 0.0130208 *  
V1                 -0.047425   0.361343 -0.1312 0.8955807    
V2                 -0.336730   0.274275 -1.2277 0.2195565    
V3                  0.291357   0.133715  2.1790 0.0293353 *  
V4                  0.214973   0.171763  1.2516 0.2107269    
V5                 -0.254565   0.127718 -1.9932 0.0462414 *  
V6                  0.025241   0.090327  0.2794 0.7799047    
V7                  0.356812   1.393241  0.2561 0.7978720    
Jan                -4.880777   1.071325 -4.5558 5.218e-06 ***
Feb                -6.279093   1.804973 -3.4788 0.0005037 ***
Mar                -6.994350   3.277484 -2.1341 0.0328378 *  
Apr                -6.156275   4.548115 -1.3536 0.1758678    
May                -6.819518   5.670635 -1.2026 0.2291303    
Jun                -6.929341   6.228455 -1.1125 0.2659105    
Jul                -5.522017   6.264116 -0.8815 0.3780301    
Aug                -4.837365   5.348722 -0.9044 0.3657852    
Sep                -3.978249   3.819513 -1.0416 0.2976161    
Oct                 0.492007   2.461915  0.1998 0.8415999    
Nov                -0.817754   1.392464 -0.5873 0.5570215    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I don't know how to interpret what happens with december month.

Thanks

Comment: [Rob Hyndman's "ARIMAX model muddle" blogpost should be exactly what you are looking for.](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) Note that your model is a regression with ARIMA errors, not ARIMAX, and the "December" factor level simply turns into the intercept. However, why do you use monthly dummies to presumably model seasonality, rather than just running a SARIMA model (more precisely, a regression on your remaining predictors, with SARIMA errors)?